# Get text from character and after using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, substring

I want to get the text from a string after the occurrence of a specific character.

Lets say: texttexttext#abc
And I want to get abc

How is this done in jquery?
(This might be trivial to somebody, but I have little exp in jQuery)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you could do:

```
var text =  'texttexttext#abc';
var abc = text.substring(text.indexOf('#') +1);
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need to use jQuery for this. Simple javascript is fine.

In this case:

```
var text = 'texttexttext#abc';
var textAfterHash = text.split('#')[1];
```

or

```
var textAfterHash = text.substring(text.indexOf('#') + 1);
```

[JSFiddle Example of both](http://jsfiddle.net/EZVMy/)

Answer (score 4):

Contrary to popular belief, jQuery isn't needed in every situation ;)

Example:

```
var x = 'texttexttext#abc';
var y = x.substring(x.indexOf('#') + 1);
alert(y); //abc
```