# Javascript/jQuery - Need to find raw text on the page, capture what follows into variable, and replace original with HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace, find

So let’s say the text KEYWORDANIMAL:(Cat) appears on a page. I want to search through the page for all instances of KEYWORDANIMAL, and then pull the actual animal, in this case Cat, into a variable to be used in another script that’ll pull in related content. I also want to replace KEYWORDANIMAL:(Cat) with an empty div with concatenated ID to be targeted by the other script (this other script is already working fine by itself).

I've been using info from several other threads here but just cannot make it all come together.

-[Find text string using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery)

-[Get text from character and after using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269150/get-text-from-character-and-after-using-jquery)

-[How do I use JQuery to replace all occurring of a certain word in a webpage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5153909/how-do-i-use-jquery-to-replace-all-occurring-of-a-certain-word-in-a-webpage?lq=1)

Here's what I have so far:

```
<p>Here is an animal: KEYWORDANIMAL(Cat)</p>

var findString = $('p:contains("KEYWORDANIMAL")').html();
var startIDString = findString.indexOf('(') + 1;
var endIDString = findString.indexOf(')');
var animalID = findString.substring(startIDString, endIDString);
var embedString1 = "<div id=\"";
var embedString2 = "\"></div>";
var embedStringFull = embedString1 + "animal" + animalID + embedString2;
alert(embedStringFull);

findString.each(function () {
    var newDIV = $(this).html().replace('KEYWORDANIMAL', embedStringFull);
    $(this).html(newDIV);
});
```

In fiddle form: http://jsfiddle.net/dC6bj/1/

I got the find part down (probably not very efficiently though), but I am clearly missing something on the replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely have to do this with JavaScript, you can use a regex replacement function:

```
var animal_regex = /KEYWORDANIMAL\((.*?)\)/g;

$('p:contains("KEYWORDANIMAL")').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var html =  $this.html().replace(animal_regex, function(match, name) {
        return '<div id="animal' + name + '"></div>';
    });

    $this.html(html);
});
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/dnuaL/**

This should be done serverside, if possible.

Comment: Thanks, if I could do it server side I would, but in this application it isn't an option.  Can you explain this line for me: 'var html =  $this.html().replace(animal_regex, function(match, name) {' Specifically how match and name are being defined?  Is that a function of replace?  Or the regex?

Comment: @Chaz: It's a replacement function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter

Answer (score 0):

For your third question on how toreplace all occurences of a certain word in a webpage use Regex.Replace like this:

```
var pagecontent = $('body').html();
var newcontent = Regex.Replace(pagecontent , @"[cat]", "dog");
&('body').html(newcontent);
```

Regex is the fastest solution for this kind of stuff.
My code example is a bit simple, it would also replace ocurrences within a tag.
or within a word for example in catamaran or .

To make it more perfect you could look for cat preceded by a space and followed by a space or a point or a comma. Read some regex tutorials for this. (It's really worth learning, once you know how to, you'll use it a lot)

Goodluck!

Comment: I like that but I would need it in a vanilla JS version. Could you add that version to your answer?