# I need to find a character and wrap the words after it with HTML tags

Tags: jquery, html, jekyll

In a list that I'm generating in Jekyll I need to wrap certain words with strong tags. My idea was use a delimiter so

```
<li>100g of |sugar</li>
```

would get turned into

```
<li>100g of <strong>sugar<strong></li>
```

The list is generated by an array in YAML,

```
ingredients:
  -name: 100 grams of |sugar
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get text from character and after using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269150/get-text-from-character-and-after-using-jquery)

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: You can't turn it into invalid HTML (well, you *can*, but please don't).

Comment: Thanks, now what should happen if the supplied string was `-name: 50ml of |crème fraîche`? Or `-name: 250g |strong plain flour`? How do you plan to determine the *end* of the `<strong>` element?

Comment: OK, at the moment I'm using something to create a variable after finding the pipe symbol based on a substring `var textAfterPipe = text.substring(text.indexOf('|') + 1);`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the strong tag is not closed so you could use something like this in your list :

```
ingredients:
     -name: 100 grams of %strongo%sugar%strongc%
```

then use this in jquery script :

```
str = str.replace("%strongo%","<strong>");
str = str.replace("%strongc%","</strong>");
```

then it will be turned into :

```
<li>100g of <strong>sugar</strong></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use markdown in your front matter :

```
---
layout: page
title: recipe

ingredients:
  - 100 grams of **sugar**
  - 200 grams of **floor**
---

<ul>
{%for ingredient in page.ingredients %}
    <li>{{ingredient | markdownify}}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

And done !

Answer (score 0):

Given the following HTML:

```
<ul class="ingredients">
    <li>100g of |sugar</li>
    <li>50ml of |creme fraiche</li>
    <li>200g of |strong plain flour</li>
    <li>3 |free range eggs</li>
    <li>2 |turtle doves</li>
    <li>1 |partridge, in a |pear tree</li>
</ul>
```

The following jQuery seems to work:

```
// iterates over the 'li' elements within the element(s) of class 'ingredients',
// uses the anonymous function of the html() method,
// the first argument ('i') is the index of the current element in the collection,
// the second ('h') is the found html:
$('.ingredients li').html(function(i,h){
    // we call replace() on the found-html,
    // finding the | character (escaped because in a regex it's an OR special character),
    // followed by a sequence of one, or more, alphanumerics, until a character
    // is found from the second set (the ^ is the NOT operator, within character-classes:
    return h.replace(/\|([\w][^|,.:?()_]+)/g,'<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

```js
$('.ingredients li').html(function(i, h) {
  return h.replace(/\|([\w][^|,.:?()_]*)/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
});
```

```css
.ingredients {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0.5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ingredients">
  <li>100g of |sugar</li>
  <li>50ml of |creme fraiche</li>
  <li>200g of |strong plain flour</li>
  <li>3 |free range eggs</li>
  <li>2 |turtle doves</li>
  <li>1 |partridge, in a |pear tree</li>
</ul>
```

References:

- JavaScript:

  - [JavaScript Regular Expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
  - `String.prototype.replace()`.
- jQuery:

  - [`html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I used this in the end:

```
$('.ingredients li').each(function() {
  var text= $(this).text();
  var textArray = text.split('|');
  $(this).html(textArray[0]+ " <strong>"+textArray[1]+"</strong>");
});
```

It works just as I want it to. I'll look at the solution offered by @DavidJacquel though. Thanks everyone for your help.